# Can a Xamarin project be built with both Visual Studio AND Xamarin Studio?

Tags: c#, ios, visual-studio, xamarin.ios

I know that you can use either of these tools for creating Xamarin projects, but can I also go between using the two of them? Ex: I am on a Mac, and my co-workers is on Windows?

I used to believe it was possible, but the moment we added the Windows project, we can no longer build for iOS.

When we try to build, we receive an error about not being able to import target WIndows.

I understand this, as I'm on a Mac. Even if I **exclude** the UWP project from the build process, it still throws this error.

**How do you write Xamarin projects on both a Mac and a Windows machine?**

Comment: Your question itself is contradictory. A Windows project in the solution is obviously not a "Xamarin project".

Comment: Why do you think that?

You can have iOS, Android, and Windows all within Xamarin.

Comment: Clearly Xamarin is for iOS and Android. Xamarin.Forms might extend to some Windows Store apps, but that's still considered Windows projects which is forced to be Windows only by Microsoft. Thus, I think this question itself cannot be answered at all, as you asked for something goes beyond the vendor support.

Comment: I don't think you understand the question, but that's OK. It was answered correctly, makes sense to me. I now have a Xamarin project which contains iOS, Android, and Windows, and I can develop it on my Mac and PC. Perfect.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, you can.  However, XS on a Mac cannot build Windows projects (although you should be able to exclude them from the build), and VS on the PC can only build iOS projects with the aid of a Mac to act as a build server.  Otherwise the solution files should be portable between the two environments.

Comment: Thank you. ". Otherwise the solution files should be portable between the two environments" is exactly what I was looking for.